# I can't log to ssh after enable UFW

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding, putty, ufw

When i try Set Up a Firewall with **UFW** on Ubuntu i start with enable port 80 and 443 for http and https but before enable ssh 
because internet probleme i lost connexion with putty so now i can't log to SSH to continue the configuration.
**Is there a solution to the problem by using 80 or 443 ports ?**

> NB: i use ovh dedicated server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH uses port 22, so you needed to have enabled that access too - you've essentially firewalled yourself out of your own machine.

Fortunately OVH should offer some sort of KVM which gives you console access to your server, from this you should be able to login and allow SSH access through the firewall, port 22 TCP and then you should be able to login to this again too. There's no simple way of doing this without going via the KVM/Console access, which is akin to having physical access to the machine.

Comment: Thanks djsmilet2k i find the KVM option in OVH manager and i was able now to add rule for ssh
thanks again